# Java/OpenCL: Checking which graphics card is enabled

Tags: java, graphics, opencl, gpu

Using OpenCL I am able to obtain a list of graphics cards available in my system (code snippet below), but I haven't found a way to determine which one is being used at runtime. Is this possible?

```
for (CLPlatform platform : CLPlatform.listCLPlatforms())
{
    for (CLDevice gpuDevice : platform.listCLDevices())
    {
        // The CPU shows up as a device, so filter it out.
         if (gpuDevice.getType() == CLDevice.Type.GPU && gpuDevice.isAvailable())
        {
            availableGPUDevices.add(gpuDevice);
            numGPUDevices++;
        }
    }
}
```

In theory I'd like to be able to add something along the lines of:

```
if (platform.getActiveGpu().getType() != AMD or NVIDIA) (pseudo-code)
{
    // show warning that a more powerful GPU is available
}
```

The only piece I'm missing is the ability to determine which GPU is active at the time. Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you!!

Clarification: by "which GPU is active" I mean I'm looking to determine, at the moment my code to check this is executing, which GPU is responsible for rendering the content on screen. My understanding is that both GPUs won't be rendering parts of the screen at the same time, so while I know it can switch quite a bit, I'd like to capture a snapshot of which GPU is running at that moment.

Comment: I have tentative confirmation that this isn't possible with OpenCL, any confirmation or denial of this conclusion would be great; and any non-OpenCL solution would also be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please make your question clear? Are you trying to figure out on which device your openCL kernels are running?

Comment: @JohnsPaul my lack of understanding might be partially to blame here, can there be one GPU responsible for rendering the OpenCL portions of what is being displayed and another that shows the rest of the screen? I didn't think there was. If my assumption holds, I just mean I'm looking to see which GPU is currently (at the time my code is executing) rendering what is seen on screen.

Comment: I might be making some dumb assumptions in the way I'm stating the question or with what I'm trying to do, I've tried to either not do that or to state those assumptions, but I wouldn't rule out user error on my part :).

Comment: @Mike: Hi I am sorry, I mostly work on GPGPU stuff and so i havent used openCL for graphics related purposes. So i dont think I am right person to answer your question. But from my experience with GPGPU stuff i think your program should specify which GPU should be used to do what. So an opencl program will be checking for all available devices and will be allocating tasks to each device depending on the program requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenCL doesn't support this.